# Вынести часть кода в отдельную функцию

Tags: python

В моем коде три раза встречается строка о подсчете комментариев -
annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).

Как мне реализовать для этого отдельную функцию:

```
def index(request):
posts = Post.objects.select_related(
    'author',
    'category',
    'location'
).filter(
    is_published=True,
    category__is_published=True,
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
).order_by('-pub_date').annotate(
    comment_count=Count('comments')
)
page_obj = paginate_page(request, posts, 10)
context = {
    'post': posts,
    'page_obj': page_obj,
}
return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)


def profile(request, username):
profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
author = profile.id
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    author=author,
).order_by('-pub_date').annotate(
    comment_count=Count('comments')
)
page_obj = paginate_page(request, posts, 10)
context = {
    'profile': profile,
    'page_obj': page_obj
}
return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', context)


def category_posts(request, category_slug):
category = get_object_or_404(
    Category.objects.filter(is_published=True,
                            slug=category_slug)
)
posts = Post.objects.select_related(
    'author',
    'category',
    'location'
).filter(
    is_published=True,
    category=category,
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
).annotate(
    comment_count=Count('comments')
)
page_obj = paginate_page(request, posts, 10)
context = {
    'category': category,
    'page_obj': page_obj
}
return render(request, 'blog/category.html', context)
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что вы не можете её сделать, это же проще простого...

```
def x():
    return Count('comments')
comment_count=x()
```

А вообще незачем делать отдельную функцию, она особо не сокращает и не упрощает код... Ну только на несколько символов:) Обычно функцию делают, чтобы сократить и упростить код на много строк=)